# Stack alignment on x86

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, sse

I had a mysterious bus error that occurred, on a x86 (32-bit) platform, when running code compiled with gcc-4.8.1 with `-march=pentium4`. I traced the problem to an SSE instruction:

```
movdqa %xmm5,0x50(%esp)
```

with esp = 0xbfffedac. `movdqa` requires the address to be 16-byte aligned, which is not the  case here, thus the bus error.

The problem does not occur if compiling with `-march=native` (this is a Core-i3 processor).

As far as I know, the only stack alignment guaranteed on Linux/x86 is 4-byte. Thus, it seems weird that the code generator should choose to use `movdqa`, without some kind of alignment check, even though there is an instruction `movdqu` for possibly unaligned accesses.

So, this looks like there is a bug in gcc.

I'm not an expert on SSE and x86 ABI, and I'd appreciate feedback before I send a bug report.

Comment: You are wrong, stack alignment on Linux/x86 can sometimes be 16 bytes. See [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf‎), [Linux foundation references](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/) and [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Comment: This is x86, not x86-64... that's the problem! The site claims: "Since GCC version 4.5, the stack must be aligned to a 16-byte boundary when calling a function (previous versions only required a 4-byte alignment.)[citation needed]" "Citation needed", I'd like to get a reference for that.

Comment: See [this comment](http://sourceforge.net/p/fbc/bugs/659/). Stack alignment on 32 bits x86/ia32 is now 16 bytes because of SSE, IIUC. And if the GCC compiler had to align stack frames for every SSE code, it would not worth the pain and runtime cost.

Comment: Ah ah, indeed I found relevant paragraphs in the gcc documentation on x86 code generation. It seems OCaml misaligns the stack (and since it shows only if calling code containing some SSE instructions...).

Comment: @monniaux, why does `march=pentium4` cause the problem and not `march=native`?

Comment: The code generated with `-march=native` is different. It contains `vmovdqa` instructions (AVX) and no `movdqa` (SSE). I suspect (it's not so easy to understand the assembly code) that the code using `vmovdqa` checks for 32-byte alignment, whereas the code emitted usind `movdqa` assumes 16-byte alignment, which is consistent with the defaults detailed in my answer. This is interesting: it means that programs compiled for Core-i3 can run slower than if compiled for P4 if the stack is 16-byte but not 32-byte aligned?

Comment: @DavidMonniaux: no, if gcc wants 32-byte stack alignment, it will *create* it without checking for it.  It will save the old ESP value (e.g. in `%ebp`) and `and $-32, %esp`.  gcc 7 and earlier have a more elaborate sequence of saving ESP for some reason, but the end result is a however much stack alignment is necessary for auto-vectorized temporaries, or for explicit `alignas(64) char buf[n]` or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

Now the default in gcc is `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` (16-byte alignment), which sets `-mincoming-stack-boundary=4`.

Problems can thus occur if gcc code using SSE is called from code generated by other compilers which have different stack alignment assumptions, such as OCaml (see [discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6038) on the OCaml bug tracker).